# jquery.js and drupal.js Producing 'Not Found' Errors, Yet the files do exist

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm having a problem where Javascript as a whole is not working on my site. When I view the html source and click on the links to the paths provided in the , I get 404 Not Found errors for 'jquery.js' and 'drupal.js' yet both files exist in the misc folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://capstone1:8082/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://capstone1:8082/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://capstone1:8082/misc/drupal.js?m1ilvw"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://capstone1:8082/misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?v=1.8.7"></script>
```

Above are the way the html appears in the source code. All 4 .js files produce the 404 Not Found error, so I'm assuming there's a problem with paths or permissions but can't figure out what. Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Does the webserver user has read access to the correct directories ?

Comment: I'm using it on a local AMP stack (the Acquia Dev Desktop stack) - how can I check and change the read access?

Comment: You will change the file permissions the same way you would for any other file on your computer. Consult your operating system's documentation for more information on that. Also, do you have any jQuery-related modules installed on your site such as jQuery update?